# Retrying asynchronous file upload on error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to upload files in a WPF-application. Everything works fine if the server responds but the application will be used in an environment with "unsafe" internet connection. So I want to retry uploading after a short break if the first attempt failed.

I tried several things with async/await and ended up with the following code. 
If the server is running everything is fine, but if not the program fails with an ObjectDisposedException in the second iteration of the while-loop.

Any ideas?

```
private void UploadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // build content to send
    content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    var filestream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
    var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    content.Add(new StreamContent(filestream), "file", fileName);
    content.Add(new StringContent(terminal_id.ToString()), "terminal_id");

    UploadTask(content);
    /*var task_a = new Task(() => UploadTask(content));
    task_a.Start();*/
}

private async void UploadTask(HttpContent content)
{
    bool success = false;
    int counter = 0;

    while (counter < 3 && !success)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("starting upload");
        success = await UploadFileAsync(content);
        Debug.WriteLine("finished upload. result " + success.ToString());
        //if (!success) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        counter++;
    }
}

private async Task<bool> UploadFileAsync(HttpContent content)
{
    var message = new HttpRequestMessage();
    message.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
    message.Content = content;
    message.RequestUri = new Uri(target_url);

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage res = await client.SendAsync(message);
            if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode) return true;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException hre)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(hre.ToString());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After moving the creation of the content into UploadFileAsync() it works. Result:

```
Task<bool> newTask;

private void UploadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    newTask = UploadTask();
}

private async Task<bool> UploadTask()
{
    bool success = false;
    int counter = 0;

    while (counter < 3 && !success)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("starting upload");
        success = await UploadFileAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("finished upload. result " + success.ToString());
        if (!success) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        counter++;
    }
    return success;
}

private async Task<bool> UploadFileAsync()
{
    MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    var filestream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
    var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    content.Add(new StreamContent(filestream), "file", fileName);
    content.Add(new StringContent(terminal_id.ToString()), "terminal_id");

    var message = new HttpRequestMessage();
    message.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
    message.Content = content;
    message.RequestUri = new Uri(target_url);

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage res = await client.SendAsync(message);
            if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode) return true;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException hre)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(hre.ToString());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think issue could be that the `content` is going out of scope?  Try creating `content` inside the `UploadTask` method.  Also, it might be worth returning a `Task<bool>` from `UploadTask` and caching it is a class level variable (so you don't have to return void).

For example:

```
Task<bool> newTask;

private void UploadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    newTask = UploadTask();

}

private async Task<bool> UploadTask()
{
bool success = false;
int counter = 0;

// build content to send
HttpContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var filestream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
content.Add(new StreamContent(filestream), "file", fileName);
content.Add(new StringContent(terminal_id.ToString()), "terminal_id");

while (counter < 3 && !success)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("starting upload");
    success = await UploadFileAsync(content);
    Debug.WriteLine("finished upload. result " + success.ToString());

    counter++;
}

return success;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid (nearly) nothing changed. The Exception is thrown in a background task but the result stays the same. But with this suggestion I moved the creation of content to UploadFileAsync() and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your file stream gets disposed/closed. You need to retry from the very beginning (`content = new MultipartFormDataContent();` etc).